# vector subscript out of range when load obj file in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to follow a tutorial online about opengl: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading.

Basically I follow the code online, the loading code is working but it is in C so I try to convert it to C++

This is what I came up with:

```
using namespace std;
bool loadOBJ(const char * path, std::vector<glm::vec3> & out_vertices)
{
    vector<glm::vec3> temp_vertices;
    vector<unsigned int> vertexIndices, uvIndices;
    ifstream file(path);
    string lineHeader;
    if (file.is_open())
{

}
else
{
    printf("Impossible to open the file ! Are you in the right path ?\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

while (!file.eof())
{
    file >> lineHeader;
    if (lineHeader.compare("v") == 0)
    {
        // load vertex
    }
    else if (lineHeader.compare("f") == 0)
    {
        // follow the fix

        vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
        vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
        vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            cout << vertexIndex[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexIndices.size(); i++)
{

    // Get the indices of its attributes
    unsigned int vertexIndex = vertexIndices[i];

    // Get the attributes thanks to the index
    glm::vec3 vertex = temp_vertices[vertexIndex - 1];

    // Put the attributes in buffers
    out_vertices.push_back(vertex);

}
return true;
}
```

I get this error:

> vector subscript out of range.

I know that I messed up with the `vector` but I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: This looks like it just needs basic debugging. Run it in a debugger, see where it crashes, and what the variable values are at the point. Chances are that one of the indices your read in is out of range for `temp_vertices`.

Comment: I am new to c++, but still , are you sure about your open and close brackets '}' '{' ? in line 18 and 20 ?. and also where does the function loadOBJ ends? and also are you sure you can use printf() in c++ ? (line 23)

Comment: bracket patch not found for '{' in line 12

Comment: @VishwaPrakashHV The braces look fine to me, it's just the indentation that's completely messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i fix this

```
        getline(file, tempBlock, '/');
        vertexIndex[0] = stoi(tempBlock);
        getline(file, tempBlock, '/');
        // Uv0
        file >> tempBlock;
        // normal0
        getline(file, tempBlock, '/');
        vertexIndex[1] = stoi(tempBlock);
        getline(file, tempBlock, '/');
        // Uv1
        file >> tempBlock;
        // normal1
        getline(file, tempBlock, '/');
        vertexIndex[2] = stoi(tempBlock);
        getline(file, tempBlock, '/');
        // Uv2
        file >> tempBlock;
        // normal2
```

basically i am readding the vertex wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file incorrectly. If you look at the [page you linked to](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/):

> ```
> 8/11/7 describes the first vertex of the triangle
> 7/12/7 describes the second vertex of the triangle
> 6/10/7 describes the third vertex of the triangle (duh)
> For the first vertex, 8 says which vertex to use. So in this case, -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000 (index start to 1, not to 0 like in C++)
> 11 says which texture coordinate to use. So in this case, 0.748355 0.998230
> 7 says which normal to use. So in this case, 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
> ```

So the 11 and the 7 in the first example line are a "texture coordinate" and a "normal". However, you are just putting these into the list of vertices to print. When you try to print vertex 11, your program crashes as there is only 8 vertices.

Quick fix, remove these two lines:

```
    vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
    vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);
```

More complete fix, remove those two lines and add a check to make sure the data file is valid:

```
 // Get the attributes thanks to the index
 if (vertexIndex >= temp_vertices.size())
 {
    cout << "Can't get vertex " << vertexIndex;
    return 0;
 }
 glm::vec3 vertex = temp_vertices[vertexIndex - 1];
```